# Subtract two times to get a duration in luxon in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, duration, qualtrics, luxon, time-difference

In my Qualtrics survey, respondents provide two times in two separate text entry questions on the same page: a time they got in bed (“11:30 PM”) and a time they got out of bed (“8:00 AM”). I need to calculate the number of minutes between these two times. The [luxon manual for duration math](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html#diffs) seems relatively straightforward. However, without much familiarity with Javascript I am struggling to make this calculation. Help would be very appreciated!